# liquibase-hibernate6: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-maven-plugin

I've tried adding **Liquibase** to my project and to get the `diff` between entities and the database I've also added `liquibase-hibernate6` to POM file.

When I try the command:

```
mvn liquibase:diff
```

I get there error:

> [WARNING] HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered,
> assuming application ...
> [WARNING]
> HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply
> JDBC connections

This is a part of the POM file:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/config/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
                <version>4.23.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

And the liquibase.properties

```
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-changeLog.xml
diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-changeLog.xml
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-new-changeLog.xml
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/forum
defaultSchemaName=public
username=postgres
password=123456
driver=org.postgresql.Driver

referenceDefaultSchemaName=public
referenceDriver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:ir.renglab.forum.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

---

The main point is that **finally it built successfully and the changelog file is created** but how can I fix the error? and what is the problem?

*PS: I'm using Spring-Boot version 3.1.3*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once solved the same issue under spring 2.6 and hibernate 5 by placing a `hibernate.properties` file with the same connection infos as the `liquibase.properties` file onto the classpath (generally the root of the `resources` folder) as well

e.g. hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?useSSL=false
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=
```

Unfortunately now under spring 3 and hibernate 6 it seems to not to work anymore.
But I am using `Gradle` instead of `Maven` now. So perhaps it still works for you.

[UPDATE] It seems to be a known issue: [Github Issue](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/381)

[UPDATE2] I was able to make it work under gradle with the hibernate.properties file by adding the location of the file to the liquibaseRuntime:
`liquibaseRuntime(javaExtension.sourceSets.getByName("main").resources.sourceDirectories)`

Comment: I tried your solution and as you said it didn't solved the problem in Hibernate v6.

Comment: Please be careful with this solution. On the github page someone mentioned the changelog is not incremental anymore, when using this solution.

Comment: Oh man, Your solution worked just with a minor change based on the github issue pages your shared. You said I should put `hibernate.properties` file in the same directory as `liquibase.properties` file exists, but I moved the `hibernate.properties` file to **root** of `resources` folder and the problem was solved.

Comment: If you correct your answer based on this reply [https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/381#issuecomment-1615721018] I'll accept that. Thanks anyway

Comment: About the incremental changelog problem you said, I've checked it and it works correctly. There is no problem with getting new changes.